# Python store data from .bat file in "collection" and update database

Tags: python

I have a directory structure with .bat files.  Those .bat files call a small application and pass it a number of parameters which result in a report that is emailed or saved, etc. based on the parameter values.

I need to catalog those reports along with the parameter options.  There are 25 different possible parameters.  A given .bat file does not reference all the parameters.

I'm hoping to store data about the .bat and it's parameters in some sort of list, but the possibility of missing parameters is tripping me up.  Should I create a list that has a placeholder for each possible parameter and store that in a list of lists?

Or is there a better way?

I have worked out most of the other bits required for my script and it will flow as follows.

```
Loop through directory:
    if .bat then
        loop through lines
            store data in structure
insert results to sql server table
```

The .bat file would look like this:

```
@echo off
start C:\ProgramPath\SomeProgram.exe ^
/o=excel ^
/g=C:\SavePath  ^
/s=spStoredProcToCall ^
/a=InitialCatalogName^
/c=ServerName ^
/f=outputFile.xls ^
/p=@param1~999=@param2~XYZ
```

I may insert the results in batch or one row at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving using a dictionary, but fully processing one object/dictionary at a time to avoid needing a collection of dictionaries.

My main function:

```
def main():
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk("Y:\\"):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(".bat"):
                d={}
                initDict(d,root,filename)
                f = open(os.path.join(root,filename))
                for line in f.read().splitlines():
                    if line[:1]=='/':
                        fieldType = line[1:2]
                        fieldValue = line.rstrip(' ^')[3:]
                        buildDict(d,fieldType,fieldValue)
                strSQL = buildQuery(d)
                print (strSQL)
                conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=someServer;DATABASE=myDatabase;Trusted_Connection=yes')
                cur = conn.cursor()
                cur.execute(strSQL)
                cur.commit()
```